# After submit i get an Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed

Tags: angular

**Error Explaination**
After i click the submit button the data is save successfully to database but the above error shows.Ill share my related code below. Is there any way to solve this issue
**my api data format**
this my api data format

```
{
  "expires_in": 0,
  "data": [
    {
      "patientPastHistoryCatID": 1,
      "phCatName": "Cardiovascular",
      "patientPastMedicalHistorys": [
        {
          "patientPastHistoryCatID": 1,
          "phCatName": "Cardiovascular",
          "patientPastHistorySubID": 1,
          "phSubCatName": "Heart Attack",
          "isActive": true,
          "isDeleted": false,
          "createdDate": "2022-05-09T00:00:00",
          "createdBy": 1,
          "updatedBy": 1,
          "updatedDate": "2022-05-09T00:00:00"
        },
]
}
```

**formbuilder**

```
 this.patientPastHistoryForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      'patientID': new FormControl(this.clientId),
      'patientPastMedicalHistoryModelLists': this.formBuilder.array([]),
      'phSubCatName': ['', Validators.required],
    });
```

**api call**
this code is used to call the data from api.

```
getPatientPastMedicalHistoryList() {
    this.clientsService.getPatientPastMedicalHistoryList(this.clientId)
         .subscribe(
           (response: ResponseModel) => {
            if (response.statusCode == 200) {
              //debugger
              this.patientPastMedicalHistory = response.data ;
              const formArray = this.patientPastHistoryForm.get("patientPastMedicalHistoryModelLists") as FormArray;
            response.data.forEach(item => {
            item.patientPastMedicalHistorys.forEach(element => {
            formArray.push(this.formBuilder.group({
              catId:element.patientPastHistoryCatID,
              catName:element.phCatName,
              subCatId:element.patientPastHistorySubID,
              SubCatName:element.phSubCatName,
              itemvalue:[]
              }))
            })
          })
            }
              else {
               this.patientPastMedicalHistory=[];
             }
           });
  }
```

**OnSubmit code**
this is the code for submit the error comes here after the data is save successfully.

```
onSubmit(event: any) {
    debugger
    if (!this.patientPastHistoryForm.invalid) {
      this.submitted = true;
 this.patientPastMedicalHistory = this.patientPastHistoryForm.value;
this.clientsService.createPatientPastHistory(this.patientPastMedicalHistory).subscribe((response: any) => {
          //debugger
          if (response.statusCode == 200) {
            //alert(response.message);
            this.notifier.notify('success', response.message);
          } else {
            this.notifier.notify('error', response.message);
          }
          
        });
      }
   }
```

**Html code**

```
<div class="col-lg-12 readmin-panel">
   <form id="patientPastHistoryForm" [formGroup]="patientPastHistoryForm">
       <div *ngFor="let pmhx of patientPastMedicalHistory;let i = index;">
              <div class="lineheader" id="{{pmhx.patientPastHistoryCatID}}"><p><a>{{pmhx.phCatName}}</a></p></div>
                <div class="row ppm ppd">
                <div *ngFor="let item of pmhx.patientPastMedicalHistorys;let j = index;" class="col-sm-4 fsize">
                        <section> <div id="left">
                            <label id="{{item.phSubCatName}}_{{item.patientPastHistorySubID}}" class="bpading">{{item.phSubCatName}}:</label></div>
                            <div id="right">
                            <mat-radio-group id="{{item.patientPastHistoryCatID}}_{{item.patientPastHistorySubID}}" matInput formControlName="phSubCatName" required class="bposi">
                                <mat-radio-button color="primary" class="lbl-wrap-radio bsize bpading" (click)="onButtonClick('Yes',item.patientPastHistorySubID,j)"  value="Yes" checked="{{item.valueItem==='Yes'}}">YES</mat-radio-button>
                                <mat-radio-button color="primary" class="lbl-wrap-radio bsize" (click)="onButtonClick('No',item.patientPastHistorySubID,j)" value="No" checked="{{item.valueItem==='No'}}">NO</mat-radio-button>
                            </mat-radio-group></div>
                        </section>
                        <!-- <mat-error *ngIf="submitted && formControls.{{item.phSubCatName}}.errors?.required"> Please select {{item.phSubCatName}} </mat-error> -->
                </div>
              </div>
       </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 d-sm-flex justify-content-sm-end pt-3 actions-btn">
              <button name="Save" mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="onSubmit($event)" form="patientPastHistoryForm"
                class="text-uppercase" [disabled]="submitted" cdkFocusInitial>{{submitted ? 'Saving...' : 'Save'}}</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add the `responseModel` output on save.  Looks like after saving, the `pmhx.patientPastMedicalHistorys`  or `patientPastMedicalHistory` is not an array.

Comment: still having same issue

Answer (score 0):

Use `console.log()` to inspect your object behavior and view it on your browser's console (`F12`)

Example:

```
onSubmit(event: any) {
// debugger
if (!this.patientPastHistoryForm.invalid) {
  this.submitted = true;
  this.patientPastMedicalHistory = this.patientPastHistoryForm.value;
  console.log(this.patientPastMedicalHistory); // check what you send in payload. this.clientsService.createPatientPastHistory(this.patientPastMedicalHistory).subscribe((response: any) => {
    //debugger
    console.log(response); // check what you got
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      //alert(response.message);
      this.notifier.notify('success', response.message);
    } else {
      this.notifier.notify('error', response.message);
    }

  });
}
```

}

Comment: im sending an object. If i have to send array then how should i send

Comment: If `this.patientPastMedicalHistory` looking good, Can I have the code of `this.clientsService.createPatientPastHistory(this.patientPastMedicalHistory)`